# Implement a filter in an Angular Partial View

Tags: java, spring, angularjs, jsp, spring-mvc

My urls are like `http://server/VRS/#/list`**(list of information)** and  `http://server/VRS/#/details/1` **(details of information)**

When a person shares directly the details view URL to someone else, the server needs to validate if the user has permission to view that.

The problem is that the urls has a hash character, I can get catch them to implement a filter.

What is the best way to implement a filter in spring with this kind of urls? Or the best approach for this?

Comment: The browser doesn't pass the hash to the server when it requests the page, so I don't think you can write a filter on the server side to check the contents of the hash. Are you making a REST call to get the details for a given id? I'd have the REST service check if the user has access to the id.

Comment: yes, I'm making rest call. So, the best approach in this case is to to check the result of the call, and if the person has not permission, make a redirect to a non-permission message page?

Comment: I would think so... you're doing the validation in the rest call anyway and that's the resource you're trying to protect, not the actual page itself.

Comment: Thanks, I think is the best solution, too